# Initialize SESSION Variable after Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, session

I have a classic user authentication with a form with email + password. If the auth is correct, I do   `$_SESSION['auth']=true`.
I use this session variable to display "logged in" content on each page like this (schematically).

```
if($_SESSION['auth']==true)
{
  echo $loggedcontent;
} 
else 
{
  echo $notloggedcontent;
}
```

Now I also have a Facebook log in. I use the Javascript SDK and it works.
Problem is, I need to set $_SESSION['auth'] to true if facebook log is correct but since the whole facebook log process is browser-side, i don't see what I can do.

For now, I use an ajax call to set the session variable like this :

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
    if (response.authResponse) 
    {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) 
        {
            //Here I make an ajax call that set $_SESSION['auth'] to true and then reload the page to display logged in content
        });
    } 
},{scope: 'email'});
```

My problem is that someone could simply call my ajax directly, ignoring the facebook process. When and how should I set logged in infos on my server ?

Comment: I think after the login you are re-directing or reloading the page ?

Comment: Yes I reload the page to display the good content

Comment: ok for setting the session could be easy if there was a combination of PHP and JS SDK used, if you are using the PHP SDK also I can give an example how to set the session after the FB login via JS, but if you are not using the PHP SDK then the server side script will not know about the connected user. So may be as u said using an AJAX u can set the SESSION.

Comment: You mean that I should use the PHP SDK ? ON the Facebook SDK tutorial, why do they recommend JS and they are almost not talking of PHP ? How are other website doing ? JS or PHP ?

Comment: Well it depends my question was if you are not using PHP SDK thats fine, in this case you can use Ajax to generate a session data. This should work fine.

Comment: Yes it works, but when I use ajax, it means that someone can directly call my ajax file with the browser, to log in, without using the facebook login process

Comment: thats right, so i was talking about having a server side SDK, using that you can see if the user is logged in or not and do whatever you want :)

Comment: Ok but why is the JS sdk mostly used among developpers ? I don't see how they can see that the user is logged wihtout using the server. Shouldn't every website use a server-side auth?

Comment: This how the login works in most of the cases. User connect via FB using JS SDK and then using the server side SDK the fbid of the user is stored in DB, so next time when they login it just checks if the FB user id is in DB or not and do the processing, if not it will create a new account on local DB, makes sense ?

Comment: _"ignoring the facebook process"_ bypassing permission?

Comment: by calling the ajax script that set auth to true directly, for instance with the URL.